# How to run some machine learning algorithm in hadoop single node local machine on data?

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, bigdata

I am new to hadoop.
I have installed hadoop-2.6.0 on my local system.
I have tested using 'jps' 6 processes are running.
I have read some tutorials which said that HDFS and MAP reduce are the two main things. I read that using Hbase and some Hive or mahaot we can store big files and run some algorithms on data. I have lots of big data file too.
What the next steps I should follow to apply some ML algorithm on the recorded data using hadoop?